# Angular 7: Good Practice Mixing jQuery with Typescript?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am currently doing a school project with a group of friends and we are all very new to Angular and TypeScript.

I have been involved in the designing part of the project and hadn't done the coding but I've recently finished my part and did a git pull.

I saw this piece of code written by my friend:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
      $(".hamburger-nav").on("click", function() {
        setHamburgerMenu();
        $(".menu").animate({
          height: 'toggle'
        });
      });
      // @ts-ignore
      $('.modal').modal({
        inDuration: 400,
        outDuration: 400,
        preventScrolling: false
      });
    }); //document ready function
  }
```

We are using Materialize CSS as our styling framework, but something is bugging me about jQuery code in an Angular 2 app, it feels weird seeing `$.ready` after an angular code of `NgOnInit`. Also, if there is event handling in Angular 2, there isn't a need to use $.on('click', ...)?

Is this piece of code wrong or correct? By using TypeScript, are we supposed (is it a good practice) to mix jQuery in a TypeScript file like this?

Sorry if this question sounds silly, I am a **complete beginner to Angular**, and my experience in Angular insofar is only *an EdX course on Angular*. 
I have also been searching on and off for the past hour and couldn't find a straight answer to this, I am just hoping to learn...!

Comment: No question is silly. In my opinion it's not good to use jQuery with Angular, because jQuery manipulates DOM whereas Angular spirit is to use angular templating to render your html. But you can do it, "it works", first google result : https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176

Comment: well, angular doesn't need jQuery at all... `ngOnInit` is the life cycle event which guarantees you to have a fully initialised component, so yes, `DOMContentLoaded` event doesn't need to be awaited... (it's already been fired at that point)... anyway, this might not be the right place to post this kind of questions... try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't like mixing them at all. You should take a look at Angular Animations to do what you are doing in this code: https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: To understand angular DOM updates you can check this : https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d

Comment: read the answer below from Jayyf9, you shouldn't use jQuery for DOM manipulation in angular. Angular will not know what you are doing to the DOM with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Its possible but Angular does not directly manipulate the DOM like JQuery and it is not the way of working that Angular wants. You can do anything in Angular that JQuery would of been used for so just research the features of Angular when you need to do something and try to avoid direct DOM manipulation with both JQuery and JS/TS itself.

[Angular Docs Fundementals](https://angular.io/guide/architecture) is a good place to look first when looking for info.